# I can't seem to figure out how to test BottomBar Navigation

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, navigation, android-espresso

I'm using the material BottomNavigationView and I'm trying to test the navigation:

Test:

```java
    @Test //fails
    fun navigationMenu_contractClicked_openContractFragment() {
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.nav_view)).perform(NavigationViewActions.navigateTo(R.id.contractFragment))
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.constraint_contract_overview))
    }
```

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/raisingBlack"
            app:itemBackground="@color/raisingBlack"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

but I get thrown this error:

> androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'click on menu item with id' on view 'Animations or transitions are enabled on the target device.

Since I'm very new to android and kotlin, I have absolutely no clue what to do to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Espresso doesn't work well with animations due to the visual state delays they introduce. You need to disable animations on your device. Firstly, enable developer options:

Open the Settings app.
Scroll to the bottom and select About phone.
Scroll to the bottom and tap Build number 7 times.
Return to the previous screen to find Developer options near the bottom.
Access Developer Options from Settings app, and under the Drawing section, switch all of the following options to Animation Off:

Window animation scale

Transition animation scale

Animator duration scale